On a Win10 PC, GetTickCount is said to be reset to 0 at 0x9FFFFFF after 776 days. Does timeGetTime() do that too?
On a Win10 PC, GetTickCount is said to be reset to 0 at 0x9FFFFFF after 776 days. This is mentioned on Microsoft's site:
GetTickCount resets to zero after approximately 776 days
Does timeGetTime() have the same problem, too?
I tried to test as below, but I gave up because I couldn't force the 776 days to change:
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

int main() {
    // 시작 시간 저장
    DWORD startTime = GetTickCount();
    DWORD startTime2 = timeGetTime();
    LONGLONG startTime3 = GetTickCount64();
    
    while (true) 
    {
        // 현재 시간 저장
        DWORD currentTime = GetTickCount();
        DWORD currentTime2 = timeGetTime();
        LONGLONG currentTime3 = GetTickCount64();

        // 시간 차이 계산
        DWORD diffTime = currentTime - startTime;
        DWORD diffTime2 = currentTime2 - startTime2;
        LONGLONG diffTime3 = currentTime3 - startTime3;
        
        // 시간 출력
        SYSTEMTIME st;
        GetLocalTime(&st);
        std::cout << "현재 날짜: " << st.wYear << "/" << st.wMonth << "/" << st.wDay << std::endl;
        std::cout << "현재 시간: " << st.wHour << ":" << st.wMinute << ":" << st.wSecond << "." << st.wMilliseconds << std::endl;
        std::cout << "GetTickCount("<< currentTime   <<"(Days:"<< currentTime / 1000 / 3600 / 24 <<")" << ") 시간 차이: " << diffTime << " 밀리초" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " GetTickCount64("<< currentTime3 <<"(Days:"<< currentTime3 / 1000 / 3600 / 24 << ")" <<") 시간 차이: " << diffTime3 << " 밀리초" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " timeGetTime(" << currentTime2 <<"(Days:"<< currentTime2 / 1000 / 3600 / 24 << ")" << ") 시간 차이: " << diffTime2 << " 밀리초" << std::endl;

    if ( diffTime > 20000 ) 
    {
            system("pause");
    }

    startTime = currentTime;
    startTime2 = currentTime2;
        startTime3 = currentTime3;

      // 5초 대기
        Sleep(5000);
    }
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

Please let me know if timeGetTime() is not initialized to 0 at 0x9FFFFFF0 after 776 days.
Per C++ call to API function ::GetTickCount() jumps ~18 days, GetTickCount() can be changed to GetTickCount64(), but timeGetTime() is being used because of the timer resolution, and I am wondering what to do.

Have you tried referring to the documentation? "Note that the value returned by the timeGetTime function is a DWORD value. The return value wraps around to 0 every 2^32 milliseconds, which is about 49.71 days." The same is said about GetTickCount. At no point is 776 days mentioned.

See GetTickCount64 this uses 64 bit tickcount, which will not run out so soon (as I already pointed out in the staging area)

Note - if you must use GetTickCount then simply use GetTickCount64 instead which has a large enough rollover window to be irrelevant unless you're measuring times approximating the end of the solar-system.

@GSerg see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/gettickcount-resets-zero-after-approximately-776-days - here the 776 days issue is documented.

@CherryDT Kind of an important clarification that should be a part of the question, to distinguish it from a no-effort RTFM question that it appears to be now.

It is a really weird magic constant too. 0x7fffffff would have been explicable as a signed vs unsigned confusion glitch but 0x9f...f0 suggests some idiot programmed it that way. It is a bit of an edge case though. Most Windows systems in regular use crash more frequently than that (most often on Tuesday nights after installing the OS updates).

@이재호 have you considered using QueryPerformanceFrequency()+QueryPerformanceCounter() yet?

timeGetTime does not suffer from the GetTickCount problem.
